# How to automatically add/set request headers to all requests using a custom format in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, format, http-headers, request-headers

In my Rails 7 project I've registered the `:custom_json` mime type:

```rb
# config/initializers/mime_types.rb
Mime::Type.register_alias 'application/json', :custom_json
```

I would like to *auto-add* the request header "Content-Type: application/json" to all requests using that `:custom_json` format. That is, when I execute HTTP requests to `/path/to/action.custom_json` or any other path using the `:custom_json` format then I would like the "Content-Type: application/json" header to be added to the request.

It seems the header is not added to all requests depending on the HTTP verb. That is, for example, when I execute GET requests then the header is auto-added; but when I execute POST and PATCH requests (where JSON data is set in the request body) then the header is not auto-added, making the request flow to fail.

For instance, if I execute the following POST HTTP request without explicitly setting the "Content-Type: application/json" header for it

```
curl "http://192.168.x.x:3000/users/action.custom_json" \
    -X POST \
    -d '{"val":{"var1":"value1","var2":"value2"}}'
```

then I get the log below (notice unparsed Parameters):

```
Started POST "/users/action.custom_json" for 192.168.x.y at 2024-02-16 07:41:04 +0100
Processing by UsersController#create as CUSTOM_JSON
  Parameters: {"{\"val\":{\"var1\":\"value1\",\"var2\":\"value2\"}}"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

I tried things like the following without success:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_custom_json_request_header, :if => :request_format_custom_json?

  private 

  def set_custom_json_request_header
    headers['Content-Type'] ||= 'application/json'
  end

  def request_format_custom_json?
    request.format.symbol == :custom_json
  end
end
```

How can I auto-add request headers such as `Content-Type: application/json` to all requests using a custom format such as `custom_json` in Rails?

Comment: i'm not sure how setting a response header like that has any effect here. you've already 
 set the format in your url, `.custom_json`, you just need to use it: `respond_to do |format| format.custom_json do render json: {status: :ok} end end`

Comment: In my controller I'm using `respond_to do |format| format.custom_json { render(:json => json_response, :status => :ok) } end` but it seems do not work as expected (for some requests as described in the question) without explicitly setting the "Content-Type: application/json" header in the request. BTW I updated the question

Comment: if you're sending json as your request then you should set `Content-Type` from the front end. `custom_json` is what you're sending back as your response (this would be an equivalent of `Accept` header). also, in a controller, `headers` is your response headers, `request.headers` is what comes in a request.

Comment: Yes, I'm sending JSON data in the request body. Is there a way to automatically add/set the `Content-Type` header by changing the request when the `custom_json` format is used/requested, even when sending JSON data in the request body? Maybe a middleware? or something else that can be handled easily with Rails?

Comment: your json data looks rather strange `{"{\"val\":{\"var1\":\"value1\",\"var2\":\"value2\"}}"=>"[FILTERED]"}` why is that whole string seems to be a key. can you show me how you're sending that request? yes you could configure a parser for a custom format https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/Parameters/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Question updated with info on how I'm sending the request

Comment: you were sending it as form-data, but this works: `curl http://localhost:3000/users/action.custom_json -d '{"val":{"var1":"value1","var2":"value2"}}' --header "Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: I know that by adding `--header "Content-Type: application/json"` to the (API) request makes it work. My intent is to make things easier/less verbose for the user of the API by automatically setting that header, hence avoiding him/her to add that info manually. My question is there because I think this is a good approach and it is possible with Rails... in the meantime I found [this](https://blog.eq8.eu/til/content-type-applicationjson-by-default-in-rails-5.html), which my help. Any advice or insight about it?

Comment: i'm not sure if changing `request.format` works in your case, but the middleware part should work, you could do `env["CONTENT_TYPE"] = "application/json" if env["REQUEST_PATH"].match?(/\.custom_json$/)`